# Create a MultiIndex with set_index() transforms 0 and 1 into booleans

Tags: python, pandas

I do use `DataFrame.set_index()` to transform two columns into a `MultiIndex`. The problem is that values with `0` and `1` are transformed into booleans `False` and `True`.

This is the initial table. Please see the values in `idx2`.

```
|    | idx1   | idx2   |   val |
|---:|:-------|:-------|------:|
|  0 | A      |        |     1 |
|  1 | B      | False  |     2 |
|  2 | B      | True   |     3 |
|  3 | C      | 0      |     4 |
|  4 | C      | 1      |     5 |
|  5 | C      | 2      |     6 |
|  6 | C      | 3      |     7 |
```

After doing `df.set_index(['idx1', 'idx2'])` the table looks like this. Look into the 4th and 5th row please and see that the integers are transformed into booleans.

```
|              |   val |
|:-------------|------:|
| ('A', '')    |     1 |
| ('B', False) |     2 |
| ('B', True)  |     3 |
| ('C', False) |     4 |  <<<< should be ('C', 0)
| ('C', True)  |     5 |  <<<< should be ('C', 1)
| ('C', 2)     |     6 |
| ('C', 3)     |     7 |
```

This happens with pandas version `1.5.3`.

The question is why this happens and if there is a way to prevent that?

Here is a full MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'idx1': list('ABBCCCC'),
    'idx2': ['', False, True, 0, 1, 2, 3],
    'val': range(1, 8)
})

print(df.to_markdown())


df = df.set_index(['idx1', 'idx2'])
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why this happens?

<strike>I think it's better to open an issue on the github.</strike>

@Timeless found an [existing issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46987)

> There is a way to prevent it?

Yes create the index yourself

```
out = df.set_index(pd.Index(df[['idx1', 'idx2']])).drop(columns=['idx1', 'idx2'])
print(out)

# Output
            val
(A, )         1
(B, False)    2
(B, True)     3
(C, 0)        4
(C, 1)        5
(C, 2)        6
(C, 3)        7
```

Comment: That's funny how we answered at the same time, +1 for the workaround ;)

Comment: No, you're a second faster :-) +1

Comment: It works in my MWE but not in my productive code. I'll have to figure out.

Comment: I found out. In my productive code the first row's index was build from `pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples()`. There are three dataframes (A, B, C) combined via `pandas.concat()`. One of them had a multiindex.

Answer (score 2):

There is an opened (*still in discussion*) issue in GitHub ([`#46987`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46987)).

From @*alonme* [comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46987#issuecomment-1263342070):

> The issue arises from the implementation of `PyObjectHashTable`, which
> in turn uses the python builtin hash. In cpython - **False and True have the same hash values as 0 and 1**, which in turn effects sets and dictionaries

> [image]
> [image]